# Почему в мой код возвращает не то что мне нужно?

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь написать код выполняющий задание курса Основы программирования на Python, автор: Национальный исследовательский университет "Высшая школа экономики", на Coursera.

**Задание**

Дан список чисел. Выведите все элементы списка, которые больше предыдущего элемента.

**Формат ввода**

Вводится список чисел. Все числа списка находятся на одной строке.

**Формат вывода**

Выведите ответ на задачу.
Пример
Тест 1
Входные данные:
1 5 2 4 3

Вывод программы:
5 4

Мой код

```
spisok = input().split()
a = 1
sled = spisok[a]

for i in map(int, spisok):
    if i < int(sled):
        a += 1
        print(sled)
    else:
        a += 1
```

Программа вместо того, чтобы подставлять на место [а] в spisok[a] новый индекс, просто один раз печатает число по индексу 1. То есть вместо перебора индексов и сравнивания чисел код просто останавливается на первом же проходе...

Comment: Что такое а и для чего оно нужно? В том, что на первом проходе ничего не останавливается, легко убедиться, добавив print в ветку else.

Comment: Я хотел чтобы на место а подставлялся новый индекс. То есть у меня сравниваются 2 числа одно из чисел списка вытаскивает i второе вытаскивает в виде среза a на место которой подставляется индекс, этот индекс обновляется при каждом проходе цикла в строке a += 1.

Comment: Обновляется не индекс, а переменная а, которая в цикле вообще нигде и никак не используется.

Comment: spisok[a] как на место этой а указывающей на индекс подставить обновляемую переменную или что то другое?

Comment: Учитесь отлаживать код, чтобы находить хотя бы такие элементарные ошибки.

Comment: spisok[a] выполняется ДО цикла.

Comment: Код заработал, спасибо.

Comment: отлично!.. ...

Comment: Вместо счетчика через `a` можно попробовать использоваться enumerate()

Comment: Поизучаю его позже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы взяли элемент код индексом `a`, теперь в `sled` лежит элемент который уже никак не связан с списком и поэтому изменение переменной `a` никак не повлияет на значение в `sled`

ваш код с небольшими изменениями

```
spisok = input().split()
a = 1
sled = spisok[a]

for i in map(int, spisok):
    if i < int(sled):
        print(sled)
    a += 1
    sled = spisok[a]
```

Если к примеру длина `spisok` это 5, то на последней итерации значение `a` будет 5 и попытка взять элемент под индексом `5` вызовет ошибку `IndexError`, поэтому последнее значение списка брать не надо. убрать последний элемент можно легко с помощью среза

```
map(int, spisok[:-1])
```

Comment: Это всё объясняет.

Comment: Теперь всё идеально, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
mylist = input().split()
```

пройдитесь по списку с помощью перебора индексов (от 1)

```
for i in range(1, len(mylist)):
    if mylist[i] > mylist[i-1]: 
        print(spisok[i])
```

```
5
4
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариацию решения, но мне хотелось узнать почему не работает именно мой код. И выше кажется объяснили мою банальную ошибку.